# My cat stepped on keyboard, now VLC has no sound

Tags: sound, keyboard, video, vlc

As described in the title, my dumb ass cat stepped on my keyboard, and now VLC has no sound.

I have determined that it is not a problem with the speakers or connection by playing youtube videos with sound. I have reset the VLC preferences, and that didn't work. I purged VLC and reinstalled it, and that didn't work.

I really don't know what it is. I started pressing random buttons but still, haven't found what button the kitty inadvertently to completely and permanently mute VLC and no other program.

Does anybody have any clues?

Comment: Was the other players play sound? if so VLC crashed

Comment: On VLC,  at the top where it says "audio", verify if under ,  "mute" hasn’t been selected :).

Comment: For the futur, this is the only advice I can do http://www.suck.uk.com/products/cat-top-scratcher/ 
Love cats :p

Comment: Mute is not selected.

Comment: I just tried downloading a Gnome video player, and the volume is turned off on that as well. May be a system problem as opposed to a VLC problem, but sound works fine on Youtube and the drum prompt sounds up when I log in or out.

Comment: I would assume cat pressed a key. Start with letter "v" :) (that one can indicate "volume" off/on ). Same for "m" (mute on/off).

Comment: I pressed every key on the keyboard (finding a lot of shortcuts that I didn't know existed)... but did not fix the sound.

Comment: @Rinzwind In VLC, `v` toggles subtitles.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and looking at one of the answers saying that he could have stepped on two key at the same time. After trying all the advice I started pressing different keys together. And Viola! I pressed the <kbd>M</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> together and my sound returned. Hope this will solve some people's problem!

Answer (score 1):

Reboot your computer. If that fails, try the following in VLC.

1. Open a video file in VLC
2. Right Click -> Audio -> Audio Track -> Disable
3. Right Click -> Audio -> Audio Track -> Track 1
4. Press Play

Comment: Those were the first two things I tried, and neither worked.

Comment: This may sound obvious but how about the volume inside the VLC app?

Comment: It's at 100% volume, and not muted.

Comment: What steps did you take to uninstall and reinstall VLC?

Comment: sudo apt-get purge vlc & sudo apt-get install vlc

Comment: what audio device is enabled in vlc? "Audio -> Audio Device"

Comment: HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)

Comment: are there any other audio devices to select in the "Audio Device" menu? Is "HDA NVidia Digital Stereo (HDMI)" the correct audio device?

Comment: That's the correct one. The only other choice is Built-In Audio Analog Stereo

Comment: Tried the "Built-In Audio Analog Stereo"?

Comment: Yep, tried it... didn't work.

Comment: I was wrong... I had the wrong audio device elected. mk444 was right. Should be using "Built-In Audio Analog Stereo." That solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  silver bullet solution:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound 
sudo apt-get install vlc alsa-base pulseaudio indicator-sound
sudo alsa force-reload
killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*; rm ~/.config/pulse
```

Go to Tools > Preferences > Audio. Change output module to ALSA audio output
Then restart your machine.

Comment: That didn't solve it.

Comment: Right click,->preferences and clicked "reset preferences". Then restarted vlc?

Answer (score 0):

1. Go into System
2. Then  sound
3. Select Applications

*Applications tab  : In VLC media player see slider volume control
may be the volume control was at nil (left hand side).*

4. Slide the control to the right gave

Comment: Nope, volume slider is to the right.

Comment: Do you speak about the same slider? You should have VLC playing a video do see the slider of VLC application. It's not the Output volume slider, but the VLC media player specific slider.

Comment: By "System", do you mean going into Tools -> preferences -> audio -> and the volume slider there?